# Closure compiler not detecting json inside script tag

Tags: html, json, google-closure-compiler

In my page I have a dynamically created section that outputs some JSON code:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
 { "@type": "WebPage"
 , "name": "page-test"
 ,"url": "/content/my-site/en/page-test"
 }
</script>
```

But when compressing the closure compiler sends this error message:

> ERROR - [JSC_PARSE_ERROR] Parse error. Semi-colon expected { "@type": "WebPage","name": "page-test-tabs","url": "/content/my-site/en/page-test"}

Can you guys please give me some guidance here for this issue?

Comment: Please post the command line used when invoking the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Closure Compiler only recognizes JavaScript.  As JavaScript,  the { opens a statement block, not an object literal.